# Python: how to interpret the outcome of np.argmax()?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max, argmax

The documentation on [np.argmax()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) says that it

> Returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis.

The examples given are straightforward:

```
In[1]: a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In[2]: a
Out[2]: array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In[3]: np.argmax(a)
Out[3]: 5

In[4]: np.argmax(a, axis=0)
Out[4]: array([1, 1, 1]) 

In[5]: np.argmax(a, axis=1)
Out[5]: array([2, 2])
```

Except in the case of

```
 In[4]: np.argmax(a, axis=0)
 Out[4]: array([1, 1, 1])
```

Since `5` corresponds to `a[1][2]`, why is it returning `array([1, 1, 1])`?

Also, if I assign

```
In[6]: b=np.array([[[2,3,4],[4,5,6]],[[3,7,1],[2,5,9]]])
In[7]: b
Out[7]: array([[[2, 3, 4],
        [4, 5, 6]],
       [[3, 7, 1],
        [2, 5, 9]]])
```

and then ask for the maximum value, why do these two return a different value?

```
In[8]: b.max()
Out[8]: 9

In[9]: np.argmax(b)
Out[9]: 11
```

Why does `np.argmax()` return the integer `11`, when that number does not even appear in the array?

Comment: If you `ravel` it , it is returning correct value IMO. Try b.ravel()[11] , the index is `11` where you have the max value `9`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `np.argmax()` returns the *index* of the maximum value, not the *value*.

In case of array `a`, each row in array `a` (you are asking per row, by specifying `axis=0`) has its maximum at index `1`, namely `3`, `4`, and `5`. The three rows are `[0, 3]`, `[1, 4]`, and `[2, 5]`. In case you asked the `argmin()`, it would have returned `array([0, 0, 0])`.

The value of `9` is the element at index `11` of the flattened array `b`.

Comment: Right, and how about `array([1, 1, 1])`?

Comment: It returns 0 which is a correct index. `numpy` has zero indexing.